# Yii2 imagine PHP

Tags: javascript, php, image, yii2, php-imagine

Hey guys) Need your help. I use ext yii2-imagine. I try to save file in quality => 50, but it's not working. Image is always saved in quality => 100. Why can it happen ?

```
   $imagine = new Image();
    $photo = $imagine::getImagine()->open($this->uploadedFile->tempName);

    $width = $photo->getSize()->getWidth();
    $height = $photo->getSize()->getHeight();

    if (($width >= $this->width) || ($height >= $this->height)) {
        $photo->thumbnail(new Box($this->width, $this->height))->save($this->uploadedFile->tempName, ['quality' => 50]);
    }
```

Comment: Try resizing resize(new Box(500,300)). It may reduce size and quality

Comment: Resize doesnt help me)

Comment: please try this way:

 Image::frame($path)
->thumbnail(new Box(100, 100))
->save($thumbnail, ['quality' => 50]);

Answer (score 0):

You should use `jpeg_quality` option:

```
$photo->thumbnail(new Box($this->width, $this->height))
     ->save($this->uploadedFile->tempName, ['jpeg_quality' => 50]);
```

See examples in [documentation](https://imagine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/introduction.html#save-images).

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation of imagine](https://imagine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/introduction.html#save-images), you can set 'jpeg_quality' setting for jpeg and 'png_compression_level' for png. In your case you can try something like that:

```
    $options = [];
    switch (exif_imagetype($this->uploadedFile->tempName)) {
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $options = ['png_compression_level' => 9];
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $options = ['jpeg_quality' => 50];
            break;
        default:
            throw new \Exception('Unsupported format');
    }
    $photo->thumbnail(new Box($this->width, $this->height))->save($this->uploadedFile->tempName, $options);
```